# How to disable #mv-tiles in google-chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

http://oi59.tinypic.com/1xh07.jpg this is what I mean..

https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome - it not works for me,

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` is not loaded by chrome. Please help, my current chrome version is 37.0.2062.120 m

Answer (score 0):

You can  temporarily disable tiles by right clicking and and deleting "mv tiles."
Unfortunately this is just for a one session page.